# Accessing Store's State in Redux From Within A Reducer Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a combined reducer with several reducers/states.  Looks like follows

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  blogs: blogReducer,
  notification: notificationReducer,
  search: searchReducer,
  filter: filterReducer,
  users: userReducer,
  loggedUser: loginReducer
});

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

in my userReducer file, i want to access the blogs state from within a function

this is in order to update my users state when a new blog post is saved.

I've tried this:

```
import store from "../store";
const { blogs } = store.getState().blogReducer.blogs;
```

and this

```
const { blogs } = store.getState().blogs;
```

but neither are working

ultimately, upon a new blog post, i'm calling a createBlog action creator and an updateUser action creator.  my user has a one to many relationship with my blog model.  I think i need to update the user's state to include the newly created blog, and figured i could just take the current blogs state, find the user and then replace their blogs with the updated state.

something like this, but also stumped on part of this.

```
const userReducer = (state = [], action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "NEW_USER":
          return [...state, action.data];
        case "UPDATE_USER":
          const { blogs } = state;
          console.log("Blogs", blogs);
          const username = action.data.id.username;
          const userBlogs = blogs.filter(b => b.user.username === username);
          const userToChange = state.find(a => a.username === username);
          const changedUser = userToChange.blogs.replace(userBlogs);
          return state.map(user =>
            user.username !== username ? user : changedUser
          );

export const updateUser = (id, blog) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { blogs } = getState();
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_USER",
      data: {
        id: id,
        data: blog,
        blogs
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you're trying to do, but all reducers receive all actions, so your `blogs` reducer can response to your `UPDATE_USER` action, if that helps.

Comment: You can't access beyond the root key of the state given to the current reducer without importing the store directly. You might want to check into redux-saga if you're going to be doing a lot of this b/c that library makes the async handling much simpler.

Comment: @DovRine - the user isn't doing anything `async` here. They've got `async dispatch =>` because they copied it from somewhere else online, not because they're doing something `async`. The OP should 1) dispatch multiple actions from the `thunk` or 2) listen to the `UPDATE_USER` action in the blogs reducer. Each reducer MUST look after IT'S OWN STATE. EDIT: Third (and probably best) option - [normalize your data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

Comment: yeah i'm obviously a very new user to redux/thunk etc, and just following along the full stack open course.  my main issue is that when i submit a new blog post, the 'blogs' state is updating, however the 'users' state is not, and i need that state in order to display a full list of users with the associated blogs

Comment: @Adam can you just guide me as to how to listen to UPDATE_USER action from within a blogs reducer.  this is the part that has me the most confused as I have no idea how to even start this.

Comment: @JohnRogerson - just add `case "UPDATE_USER":` inside your blogs reducer, all your reducers receive the same actions.

Comment: Oh wow had no idea I could do that ..thanks!

Comment: @Adam, don't you mind adding that as official answer? Then it could be helpful from someone else later.

Comment: I added a solution based on Adam’s advice.  If he wants to post an answer for credit, more than happy to give him the upvote

Answer (score 1):

There is a FAQ part in the Redux documentation about this issue:
https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers

You could use [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers) for example:

```
// In this reducer, the state argument represents your root state
// Here you can handle actions which need to access multiple slice of the root state
const specializedReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_USER":
      const { blogs, users } = state;
      // proceed with your code here
  }
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
  blogs: blogReducer,
  notification: notificationReducer,
  search: searchReducer,
  filter: filterReducer,
  users: userReducer,
  loggedUser: loginReducer
});

const rootReducer = reduceReducers(specializedReducer, reducer);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

Answer (score 1):

so, as suspected, I was overly complicating things.  thanks to the back and forth here, i realized that I could call another listener from another reducer.  thus this is how i solve my issue.

in my user reducer i added a case "USER_POSTED_BLOG"

```
 case "USER_POSTED_BLOG":
      return [...action.data];
```

and then in my blog reducer i added an additional dispatch to that newly created case, which would grab all of the users and update the state after the new blog is created

```
export const createBlog = content => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const newBlog = await blogService.create(content);
    dispatch({
      type: "NEW_BLOG",
      data: newBlog
    });
    const updatedUsers = await userService.getAll();
    dispatch({
      type: "USER_POSTED_BLOG",
      data: updatedUsers
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your state value in the reducer you don't need getState().  The state value is the first argument in your reducer.  So you just call the state in your reducer.  If you want to get the state value in your action then you can use getState. Also if you want to extract blogs object from the state object you are going one too far.

Your are doing this:

```
const { blogs } = store.getState().blogs;
```

and it should be this:

```
const { blogs } = store.getState();
```

Here is an example.

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  //your initial state
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "UPDATE_USER":
      // just use the state object
      const { blogs } = state;
      const username = action.data.id.username;
      const userToChange = blogs.find(a => a.username === username);
      const blogsNeedToChange = userToChange.blogs
      const changedUserBlogs = ?????????????
      return state.map(user =>
        user.username !== username ? user : changedUserBlogs
      );
  }
}
```

Action:

```
export const updateUser = (id, blog) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { blogs } = getState();
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_USER",
      data: {
        id: id,
        data: blog,
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: `getState` is the second argument (after `dispatch`) passed to the `thunk`. You shouldn't be `import`-ing store in the action.

Comment: Also, a `thunk` can `dispatch` as many actions as it wants, so that's probably the best course of action for the OP.

Comment: @Adam I didn't see in his store that he applied thunk I just copied his code real quick but I edited my answer.  Also I agree that he should probably keep the reducer pure and do all of the logic in the action but his question was how to get the state in the reducer I'm not going to refactor his code.  I just added the getState in the action so he could see the difference between getting the state in the action vs the reducer.

Comment: Letting the OP get state belonging to one reducer in another reducer goes against the entire core concept of redux. This is JavaScript, you can do anything you want, but don't. dispatch multiple actions from the thunk, or listen to the `UPDATE_USER` action in the blogs reducer. By suggesting what the OP is doing is ok perpetuates really bad practice not only to the OP, but to anybody who happens to come across this question. Don't supply bad answers just because you don't want to "refactor his code".

Comment: thanks for the answer Steve, i updated my code above using your suggestions, but i'm getting an error `No reducer provided for key "users"` ..not sure if this is something i'm doing wrong in my updateUser action creator

Comment: @JohnRogerson I don't think it has to do with your action creator it probably has to do with your reducer but I could be wrong.  If i had to guess its probably the return statement you have in your userReducer.  You are mapping through the state and in your map function you have user as an arguement but you are going to map through your reducers and not the users try state.users.map.  That said I think you should do all of your logic in your action then just pass the finished data to your reducer it would make things much easier.  Your reducer should be pure and without logic just data.